# Is there a y offset for bottom sheet?

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

I am trying to determine where my BottomSheet is on my screen. I would like to be able to do something similar to this.

```
<ScrollView
  onScroll={event => { 
    this.yOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
  }}
>
```

Now while this is for ScrollView, it gets my point across of what I am trying to accomplish.

[This is the library](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/props/#activeoffsetyhttps://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/props/#activeoffsety) I am using for my BottomSheet. I noticed there is a animatedPosition and a onChange prop but zero examples. **How can I accomplish this for BottomSheet?**